# Drupal : Can I have sound and playback at the same time?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

My site is built with Drupal.
I have integrated a player on my website reacheable with [www.alafiatv.bj](http://www.alafiatv.bj) But when I unmute the sound, the video playback stops. Even if I restart playback, it doesn't work until I mute the sound.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Your help will be useful to me.

I would like to fix the fact that playback stops as soon as the sound is activated. Thus, visitors will be able to have the reading accompanied by sound.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.